# C# using a library - compile from source? Really?

Tags: c#, compilation

I'm not very experienced in C#, done some small stuff with it, but it's quite similar to Java, only different, so no fuss. For my current project I need a small web server. So I've been looking around and found that a lot of people are doing a HttpListener based thing. Great, I can do that, but I also ran into the Kayak web server (https://github.com/kayak/kayak) and I figured using a little more seasoned framework may be a good idea.

So I started to try and add it to my project; searching for a DLL to add. But it seems I'm suppose to check out the source and compile it using Rake. Really? Is that how frameworks in C# are distributing; 'old' style Unix "please compile me"? Expecting something like Maven may be too much, but... Or is this an exception?

Comment: It depends on the project; some people will distribute source, some people will distribute compiled assemblies, some people will distribute both, and some people distribute installers!

Comment: are you using microsoft visual studio for your web project ? Do you have IIS running on windows server ? Apache web server is available on many platforms too.

Comment: IMO source only is fine if all you need to do is open a `sln`/`csproj` file and hit compile. If you need a complex build process, binaries are nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some open source projects need you to compile them from scratch - others provide [NuGet](http://nuget.org/) packages. Often a project won't have a pre-packaged build until they reach v1.0, for example.

In the case of Kayak, there *is* a [NuGet package](http://nuget.org/packages/kayak), so that's probably what you should use.

Note that NuGet is only "reasonably" new (last couple of years) so there will be old, stable projects which haven't required any changes recently which may not have packages, and you may well find many developers who are going to *use* the project who aren't familiar with NuGet.

Comment: Ohhhkay... NuGet seems nice. However the install instructions (http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/installing-nuget) do not match what I see on my screen (VS C# 2010 express). The search on "nuget" does not find the "NuGet Package Manager", there is a "NuGet Packager" but that seems to be for generating stuff, not importing. I downloaded the NuGet.Tools.vsix manually, but double clicking it did not make me happy; the file was not recognized. And the Extentions folder is not playing nice (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saraford/archive/2010/03/11/how-to-install-visual-studio-extensions.aspx).

Comment: Downloaded the command line NuGet. Apparently I've installed Kayak 0.7.2, now to figure out what that means.

Comment: @tbeernot: The Express edition of Visual Studio doesn't support plugins, which is probably why it wasn't working for you.

Comment: I do have the extention manager and it does find extentions, only not the "NuGet Package Manager". I've found that Express editions only install extentions of type Template or Control.

Answer (score 2):

You are definitely looking for: http://nuget.org/packages/kayak

[NuGet](http://nuget.org/) can be used from command line or as a Visual Studio addon - both work very well.